Next.js App Build Fails on AWS Amplify with Missing deploy-manifest.json Error
I'm trying to deploy a Next.js application on AWS Amplify, and it builds fine locally. However, when I push my changes to Amplify, the build fails with an error stating that deploy-manifest.json cannot be found. My application uses both SSR (Server-Side Rendering) and SSG (Static Site Generation) features of Next.js.
Here is the buildspec.yml file I'm using:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*

From what I understand, AWS Amplify should automatically handle SSR and SSG build processes for Next.js applications. My package.json scripts are as follows:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
},

Full error:
2024-04-08T12:43:52.887Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Failed to find the deploy-manifest.json file in the build output. Please verify that it exists within the "baseDirectory" specified in your buildSpec. If it's not there, we will also check the .amplify-hosting directory as a fallback. When using a framework adapter for hosting on Amplify, double-check that the adapter settings are correct.
I've checked the AWS Amplify documentation for deploying Next.js applications but haven't found a solution that addresses this specific issue. Is there a step I'm missing, or a specific configuration required for Amplify to find or generate the deploy-manifest.json file for a Next.js app with SSR and SSG?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
